# How can I get the ActiveModel::API reference to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I have an existing simple rails app that I'm trying to modify.
I'm working on getting an ActiveModel model to work in this app (existing models all use dynamoid). I built the class and was able to get it to successfully populate a `show` view.
However, everything blows up when I try to switch to an `edit` view.
I believe the fix for this is to add `include ActiveModel::API` inside the class.
At least that is what the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) seem to suggest.

However, when I do that, I get

> NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveModel::API)

I found the right gem and installed it `gem install activemodel` and then tried again, but even with the right gem, the same error occurs. I've tried restarting the rails app - no luck. I've tried adding in a `require 'active_model'` at the top of the file (as suggested in some probably unrelated github issue) - no luck. I dug through the gemfile.lock and found that it already required an older version of activemodel, so I uninstalled the newer version and installed the older version, restarted rails again, but no luck. Searching for the error message results in red herrings - usually dealing with class-referencing issues within an app rather than with referencing a gem.

If it matters here are my versions:

- ruby: 2.7.4
- activemodel: 6.1.3.1
- rails: 6.1.3.1

Here is what the beginning of my class looks like:

```rb
# app/models/complex_model.rb
require 'active_model'

class ComplexModel
  include ActiveModel::API
```

My question: How can I get past this uninitialized constant issue?

Comment: ActiveModel::API was introduced in Rails 7. Either update the app, or include the consisting modules yourself.

Comment: Protip: on the right corner on the docs is a huge banner with the version. For Rails 6 you want https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/

Answer (score 0):

You're using the docs for the wrong version of Rails.

[ActiveModel::API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/API.html) was introduced in Rails 7. And frankly there is not a whole lot going on if you strip the comments out:

```
module ActiveModel
  module API
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    include ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment
    include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion

    included do
      extend ActiveModel::Naming
      extend ActiveModel::Translation
    end

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      assign_attributes(attributes) if attributes

      super()
    end

    # Indicates if the model is persisted. Default is +false+.
    #
    #  class Person
    #    include ActiveModel::API
    #    attr_accessor :id, :name
    #  end
    #
    #  person = Person.new(id: 1, name: 'bob')
    #  person.persisted? # => false
    def persisted?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

What they did is basically shuffle the parts out of the [`ActiveModel::Model`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) module into yet another layer. `ActiveModel::Model` consists of parts that where abstracted out of ActiveRecord in Rails 5 and made usable for non-database backed models and as a foundation blocks for building things like Object Relational Managers and even API client data wrappers.

The idea is that `ActiveModel::API` will contain just the bare necissities needed to interact with stuff like the polymorphic routing and the I18n module while `ActiveModel::Model` will at some point include `ActiveModel::Attributes` which is incompatible with ORMs that provide their own attributes implementation such as ActiveRecord.

Whatever you're doing in Rails 6 you can probally solve it simply including `ActiveModel::Model` and `ActiveModel::Attributes`.